# Reduce array of associative arrays to associative array

Tags: php, arrays

Is there an idiomatic way (some existing function) to reduce

```
[[0 => 'zero'], [1 => 'one']]
```

to

```
[0 => 'zero', 1 => 'one']
```

?

It is easy to just create a loop that does the job, but it seems inefficient, and I would clearly prefer a one-liner here.

Edit: Oh, and it is just random here that 0 and 1 follow each other. The array could also be `[[2 => 'two'], [3 => 'three']]`

Comment: when downvote, please state in a comment why. I find my question totally valid

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca right, I don't. I just heart about the tendency on SO to just distribute downvotes here and there migh drives the entire network less usable. This is a bad tendency and I try to counteract it, when possible. But for me personally, yeah, whatever

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `array_merge` with `...` splat operator

```
$a = [[0 => 'zero'], [1 => 'one']];
print_r(array_merge(...$a));
```

**Solution II: Preserve keys**

```
$a = [[1 => 'one'], [0 => 'zero']];
$r = [];
array_walk($a, function($v, $k) use (&$r){ $r += $v;});
print_r($r);
```

Working demo : https://3v4l.org/9sRaE

Comment: Or `call_user_func_array` when `...` is not supported.

Comment: Wow, that's what I call a one-liner!

Comment: Note that this ignores the keys in the original array, so if `[1 => 'one']` is the first item in the array it becomes `0 => 'one'` in the output: https://3v4l.org/6UopE

Comment: @naththedeveloper oh, but this is actually important here

Comment: @IceFire solution II has the preserve keys

Comment: @RakeshJakhar well, I know `array_walk` but hoped that there was a shorter way because this is only a one-liner by low standard. Anyway, not the point to complain. If this is the shortest way, I'm fine with it! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want keys preserved, and assuming that in the case of conflicting keys, you want the first value, `array_reduce` is well-suited to the task.

```
$r = array_reduce($a, function ($acc, $v) { return $acc + $v; }, []);
```

This is functionally identical to @Rakesh Jakhar's solution. I think it's semantically more faithful to the problem and avoids having the initialize `$r` and the `use` clause.

In php 7.4, this could be written a bit nicer with an arrow function:

```
$r = array_reduce($a, fn($acc, $v) => $acc + $v, []);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php